# Rails Devise restrict IP address access for admin users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My project uses Devise for authentication (fairly standard). Users can be either normal users or administrator users.

I now have a requirement to restrict login for administrator users to some IP addresses (behind the firewall).

I briefly considered to use a Rails routing constraint, but this is not applicable, since ordinary users and admin users log in through the same login page.

So, what I want is:

1. let Devise handle authentication
2. hook into the authentication cycle and verify administrators:
3. If logged in user is of type: administrator, then verify IP address
4. If valid IP, then continue
5. If IP address is not within accepted range, then don't login

How should I hook into the Devise login cycle here? And how do I either accept or reject the login attempt based on my custom validation?

I am using Rails 4.2 and devise 4.1 if that is relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use Devise for this.  Let them log in, user or admin - just base access to certain controllers on their ip address.  Redirect if they don't have access.

Make an admin namespace and base controller.  You can add this to routes easily.  Subclass all other admin related controllers from the admin base controller so they inherit the before action.

```
class Admin::BaseController > ApplicationController
  before_action require_valid_ip

  def require_valid_ip
    # Test for IP.  Redirect if bad
  end 

end
```

Other classes would be subclassed from the BaseController

```
class Admin::OtherController > Admin::BaseController


  ...
end
```

You can also put a lot of this in an Authorization gem like CanCan, though that can also be overly complicated if your needs are simple.

Comment: Agree with this. Your IP (or the people you want to verify) might change, or in fact disappear altogether.