# Inherited Devise controller tweaking for admin role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to customise a Devise model (Admin) and perform a few check on login. I have then added a few fields that need to be validated before a sessions is created.

controllers and views have been generated for Admin model.

The inherited sessions controller looks like this :

```
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  protected


  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

One of these validation is checking the currently logging admin IP address against a stored value (with dedicated field populated manually after admin creation).

I have two questions :

- Let's say I modify the create method, do I still inherit every `protected` and `private` method from the original controller (here : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb )
- Also is it safe to modify the create method with only `super` in it, and append an `after_action :check_validity` which will check  the IP of the newly logged in admin? Or should I hard tweak the original create method ?

Comment: Point #2: I think you want to check the validity *before* calling `super` in the `create` action. If it is not valid, the end-user should not be allowed to sign-in as admin (or I misunderstood the whole point of this feature).

Comment: Hi MrYoshiji. I am trying to prevent the admin to log from a funny IP, in case the admin session has been stolen. Then the verified IP is stored into the admin profile. I was planning to check this way : `unless request.remote_ip == current_admin.verifiedip1`... etc .. Can I access the admin data before he is logged ?

Comment: Ok I realise thats silly. I have to actually perform this check inside my admin namespace and check the logged in admin against stored IP in every controller of the namespace.. If the session is stolen, checking at login stage is stupid ... (I can still do it in case admin credentials has been stolen, or a fired admin trying to log in from home)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. All of the `protected` methods will be inherited from the parent controller.  However, you will not be able to call the parent's `private` methods directly from the `Admins::SessionsController`.  All of the `before_action`s will execute normally and you will not need to replicate them in the inherited class.
2. I agree with MrYoshiji here.  You should probably make your ip check a `before_action` so that it happens before the parent's `create` method renders a page to the user.  However, you will not have a `current_admin` available until after `super` executes, so you will either need to find another way of identifying the admin user or you should modify the `create` method completely without using `super`.
3. You might also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665983/rails-devise-restrict-ip-address-access-for-admin-users) for a solution.

Comment: great thank you Tom. Then  basically for number 1, I have to copy over all `protected` and `private` to avoid any loss of functionnality from original Devise controller. For number 2, I can maybe copy over but the last line `respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` so that I am not redirected to a specific view and perform my additional checks on the logged in admin ... Keeping after_action allows login functionnality to make most of the job (if I am not missing anything)

Comment: Regarding #1, I do not think you need to copy over the protected methods.  Private methods explicitly called in `create` may need to be copied over.  I'd try running it without copying anything over, and if you get errors, copy only the ones you need.   Regarding #2 you may need to do your IP check before the last TWO lines in the `create` controller. If I am reading the code correctly, either of the last two lines could cause a redirect or a render.

Comment: it's perfect with last 2 lines commented.I have copied over all private and protected. I will check if really relevant next days. Thanks